# Why does this absolute ul move out of its parent?

Tags: html, css, position, display

Why does the ul element get the full width of the wrapper element when the container div is its parent? And how can I change this?

Structure of the HTML:

```
Wrapper
  | container
       | label
       | input
       | ul
       | botton
```

HTML & CSS:

```css
.wrapper{
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
  
.country-input {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
  
ul {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <label for="country">State</label>
    <input class="input country-input" id="country" type="text" />
    <ul id='country-list'>
      <li id="US">United States</li>
      <li id="AF">Afghanistan</li>
      <li id="AX">Åland Islands</li>
      <li id="AL">Albania</li>
    </ul>
    <button>explore</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a link](https://repl.it/join/vxamrxss-elireiner) to the full code

This is how it looks:

[here](https://i.ibb.co/m5RfC24/Screen-Shot-2020-07-25-at-1-59-18-PM.png)

On the left you can see the negative position the element gets:

[here](https://i.ibb.co/D4fprSG/Screen-Shot-2020-07-25-at-1-59-07-PM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just because your `<ul>` tag is using padding. Look at snippet and tell me is that what you're looking for?

```css
.wrapper{
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 200px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto
  }
  
  .country-input {
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  ul {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    top: 20px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  li {
    padding-left: 40px;  

  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <label for="country">State</label>
            <input class="input country-input" id="country" type="text" />
            <ul id='country-list'>
                <li id="US">United States</li>
                <li id="AF">Afghanistan</li>
                <li id="AX">Åland Islands</li>
                <li id="AL">Albania</li>
            </ul>
            <button>explore</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using select + option tags instead of unordered list.

Example:

```
<select id='country-list'>
  <option id="US">United States</li>
  <option id="AF">Afghanistan</li>
  <option id="AX">Åland Islands</li>
  <option id="AL">Albania</li>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

set in the `ul` tag - `width: unset`, `left: 0` and `right: 0`

```css
.wrapper{
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 200px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto
  }
  
  .country-input {
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  ul {
    height: 200px;
    width: unset;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <label for="country">State</label>
            <input class="input country-input" id="country" type="text" />
            <ul id='country-list'>
                <li id="US">United States</li>
                <li id="AF">Afghanistan</li>
                <li id="AX">Åland Islands</li>
                <li id="AL">Albania</li>
            </ul>
            <button>explore</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please set the style of ul, padding:0px;